# Finding Inverse Laplace Transform (Using the table of Laplace transform)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I want to take the inverse laplace transform of $$\frac{e^{-s}}{s(s^{2}+1)}$$

So I separate the equation into $$e^{-s}\times\frac{1}{s(s^{2}+1)}$$

Now, I take the partial fraction of $\frac{1}{s(s^{2}+1)}$.

I get $$\frac{A}{s} +\frac{Bs+C}{s^{2}+1}$$

$$\frac{A(s^{2}+1)+(Bs+C)s}{s(s^{2}+1)}$$

After solving for A,B,C I get $A=1$,$B=-1$,$C=0$

And substituting back to the equation, I get $$\frac{1}{s} -\frac{1}{s^{2}+1}$$

Then by the 2nd shifting property,$$\mathcal{L}(e^{-s}\times\frac{1}{s} -\frac{1}{s^{2}+1})$$

My final answer is $$u(t-1)(1-sin(t-1))$$ but the answer provided is $$u(t-1)(1-cos(t-1))$$

---

Could someone help me verify? Thanks

Comment: **Hint**: Your partial fraction should be: $\dfrac{1}{s}-\dfrac{s}{s^2+1}$.

Comment: @Variable yes, but I can't seem to get it!!

Comment: You wrote, $\dfrac{A}{s} +\dfrac{Bs+C}{s^{2}+1}$ and you correctly found the constants as $A=1, B=-1,C=0$. Do you see the simple error now? This is exactly the hint - a very simple transcription issue. Lastly, look at item $8.$ and $25.$ at: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf

Comment: @Variable GOTCHA! Thanks!!